# Obtener diferencia de días entre dos fechas

Tags: java, jsp

Soy nueva en java y quisiera saber como puedo calcular la diferencia de días entre una fecha de inicio y la fecha actual del sistema.
La fecha de inicio la recibo de un `<input type="date" >` pero ya hice la conversión a date, ya obtuve la fecha actual del sistema ahora me podrían dar una mano para calcular diferencia de días muchas gracias.
Mi código.

```
// Conversion de string a date
String Dateinicio = request.getParameter("addtimeinicio");
Date fechaInicio = date.parse(Dateinicio);

// Aca tengo la fecha actual

Date fechaactual = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

// Operacion

 int dias = (int) ((fechaInicio.getTime() - fechaactual.getTime()));

 System.out.println("Hay " + dias + " dias de diferencia");
```

Comment: Comparte el código de lo que hasta ahora has intentado, para la comparación de las fechas

Comment: OK, ya la edite.

Answer (score 2):

**Lo primero es que para comparar dos fechas deberán tener el mismo formato.**

Tu programa cuenta con una fecha que se introduce en el sistema (entrada) y una fecha que la da el propio sistema (fecha actual).

Si la fecha del sistema tiene el formato `"yyyy-MM-dd"` se usará este pára *formatear* la fecha de entrada, invirtiendo el orden en tu código:

```
// Conversion de string a date
String Dateinicio     = request.getParameter("addtimeinicio");
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date fechaInicio      = date.parse(Dateinicio);

// La fecha actual
Date fechaactual = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

**Lo que vas a hacer a continuación es obtener unidades con las que operar.**

Un día se compone de horas, minutos, segundos... milisegundos. Y las fechas son marcas de tiempo medidas en milisegundos desde un momento inicial en el tiempo... el punto de partida. Entonces pasas las dos fechas que tienes a milisegundos, restas una a la otra y divides el resultado entre el número de milisegundos que tiene un día:

```
int milisecondsByDay = 86400000;
int dias = (int) ((fechaactual.getTime()-fechaInicio.getTime()) / milisecondsByDay);
```

Comment: Cabe aclarar que 86400000 ms/dia = 24 hr/dia x 60 min/hr x 60 seg/min x 1000 ms/seg.

Comment: El problema de este método es que no se ajusta a lo que la gente entiende por "dias". Calcular la diferencia entre las 12:33 de hoy y las 00:01 de mañana da "0 días", pero para la mayoría de la gente hay una diferencia de un día. La gente no entiende que la diferencia en días cambie mañana a las 12:33. El método de JGarnica es más intuitivo.

Answer (score 2):

Si usas java 8 has uso de la clase [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) y [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String  requestDate = "2020-01-15";
    LocalDate myDate = LocalDate.parse(requestDate);

    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();

    long numberOFDays = DAYS.between(myDate, currentDate);

    System.out.println(String.format("The diff of days is %d",numberOFDays));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple si estás limitado y no puedes usar Java 8 o +, y sin que afecten los cambios de hora :

```
/**
 * Devuelve los días entre 2 fechas
 * @param fechaDesde
 * @param fechaHasta
 * @return
 */
public static long diasEntreDosFechas(Date fechaDesde, Date fechaHasta){
     long startTime = fechaDesde.getTime() ;
     long endTime = fechaHasta.getTime();
     long diasDesde = (long) Math.floor(startTime / (1000*60*60*24)); // convertimos a dias, para que no afecten cambios de hora 
     long diasHasta = (long) Math.floor(endTime / (1000*60*60*24)); // convertimos a dias, para que no afecten cambios de hora
     long dias = diasHasta - diasDesde;

     return dias;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución c: Podrías explicar lo que hace tu código por favor? Puedes hacerlo añadiendo comentarios en este que expliquen lo que hace la linea de abajo.

Comment: Puedes dar un vistazo a este contenido [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Llegando al mismo resultado con:

```
long fechaInicialMs = fechaInicial.getTime();
long fechaFinalMs = fechaFinal.getTime();
long diferencia = fechaFinalMs - fechaInicialMs;
double dias = Math.floor(diferencia / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

**Math.floor():**
Este método devuelve el entero más grande que es menor o igual que el argumento. Devuelto como un doble.

**Ejemplo Math.floor():**

> Si se pasa 45.95 a getFloor, éste devuelve 45; si se le pasa -45.95,  devuelve -46.

Se divide por 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60, ya que el valor que se obtiene de getTime() es en  milisegundos. Por consecuencia se debe obtener su equivalencia en días:

**86,400,000 =  (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60*)**

> 1000 milisegundos = 1 segundo
>
> 60 segundos = 1 minuto
>
> 60 minutos = 1 hora
>
> 24 horas = 1 día